# Приложение не видит ресурс c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно чтобы при наведении на изображение оно менялось, всегда пользовался вот так:

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/close1.png"));
```

Но сейчас почему-то ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во первых такое делается в XAML, при помощи триггеров. Во вторых, проверяйте свойства у изображения, возможно вы ему убрали внедрение в ресурсы приложения.

Comment: Наличие файла в решении не гарантирует его публикацию в каталоге ресурсов.

Comment: В действиях при сборке я указывал и внедренный ресурс, и просто ресурс - ничего не помогло. Я пробовал через xaml, но у меня не получилось. Вот что делал: https://imgur.com/a/A1CEZqD

Comment: В XAML уж скорей всего будет `/ВашNameSpace;component/Resources/close1.png`, ну или просто `Resources/close1.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, я делал библиотеку(dll), поэтому там надо было писать так:

```
/Dll.dll;component/Resources/close1.png
```